# Do you have to parse text in order to extract PDF file or can you extract PDF file without Parsing first to read specific text words?

Tags: parsing, pdf, power-automate, pdf-extraction, power-automate-desktop

Currently we are utilizing the Solimar system to send PDF invoice files daily (that contains different customers) into a specific folder (via a batch job -> one big PDF file). The invoices are also printed locally on a daily basis and delivered to us by our DexImaging vendor team. The invoices we receive locally are then separated out by customer and mailed to their respective locations. For a few customers, we scan the invoices over to them utilizing our BizHub prior to mailing.

Thought: I believe there is a way utilizing Power Automate or Power Apps to create a dedicated flow (potentially utilizing parse text and/or extract PDF file pages to a new PDF file (Which will be housed either in OneDrive or SharePoint folder)).

Ask: Is there a way to accomplish this and will the files in the PDF need to go through a Parse text to read the specific verbiage in order to determine the correct files to extract from the total pages in the PDF file? The extracted PDF files would need be copied to a respective folder in OneDrive/SharePoint. Further, since the respective text, may not always be on the same page, how would I go around the page selection (Single page or range) option that automate forces you to add?

Thanks for any assistance as this would alleviate a huge piece of manual work that is done daily.

[image: Flow ex: worked on today]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do; please add more detail to your second paragraph.